# plot multiple column using subplot of a single data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

*I am new to python*

I have a few Pandas Data Frames having different columns

I am trying to plot different column using subplot plot as subplots, but I'm unfortunately failing to come up with a solution to how and would highly appreciate some help.

I also tried few things pasting the code below but I am getting the error -**'AxesSubplot object is not subscriptable'**

```
enter code here
df = pd.read_csv('D:\data_ana\\file_r.csv')
figure , axis = plt.subplots(1,1)
axis[0,0].df.plot(x = "Age", y = ["K_DistX","K_DistY"],
    kind="line", figsize=(5, 5))
axis[0,1].df.plot(x="Age", y=["K_VabsX","K_VabsY"],
    kind="line", figsize=(5, 5))
# display plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are a newbee, here is an explanation of your given error

AxesSubplot, is the object you create in this line of code, to be exact your axis variable

```
figure , axis = plt.subplots(1,1)

axis[0,0].df.plot(x = "Age", y = ["K_DistX","K_DistY"],
```

When you do this line of code, python be like wtf. Since the AxesSubplot is not an mutable interator he gives you that error

So basically what you need to do is to stop slicin the axis object this will stop giving you that specific error, but unfortunately for you there are other issues in your code but they seen to be pretty basic stuff like what is a df object and so on i would recommend you study a little more.

```
axis.plot(x_axis_data,y_axis_data)
```